# how to get sum of same values present in the column in mongodb(robomongo)

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using mongodb. My collection name is **st_salesquotes** Here, I have attached the db columns image. [image: salequote]

I want to get the LastStatusName with their count. For example:

status   Noofstatus
Dropped    1
contacted  2
if the laststatus name is repeated again the noofstatus should display has 3 how to achieve this in mongodb query. please help me

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, this is your needed query  [Try it mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTD9vfY8XpF)
[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$group" : {"_id" : "$LastStatusName","count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},
  {"$project" : {"_id" : 0,"LastStatusName" : "$_id","count" : "$count"}}
])
```